# A cryptographically signed counter as a session identifier

Tags: digital-signature, sessionid, websecurity

[According to OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#session-id-properties): session identifiers must be unique. They must also be unpredictable to mitigate guessing attacks and sufficiently long to mitigate brute force attacks.

But what if the identifier is cryptographically signed and stored in a properly secured cookie? Then perhaps a simple counter could be the identifier. That would ensure uniqueness. But would the signature mitigate these attacks?

I ask because random identifier generation seems to leave the possibilities for both vulnerability and a hung system (identifiers must be generated until a unique one is found). This method seems to obviate both.

I understand that these concerns are not likely to occur.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include example session ids your system/framework will generate and several session ids you propose with your idea of signing the identifier. Also write the length of these session ids and explain why one of the session ids should be "weak" against the attacks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're basically using your crypto algorithm as a random number generator. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with that, but most people solve this problem by using a globally unique identifier (GUID), and just pick one long enough that the chance of collision is not worth worrying about.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Notice that [RFC 4122 section 6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-6) itself says that UUIDs "should not be used as security capabilities (identifiers whose mere possession grants access)", and that includes session identifiers and bearer credentials.

Comment: Good point @PeterO., that's fascinating. The same section also says "Do not assume that UUIDs are hard to guess". IDK, I mean GUID is basically a format for data, like UUEncode or base64. If you know you have a secure random number and you format it as the GUID you're safe. If you use a GUID generator that uses a weak RNG you are not. Bears though for sure.